# Custom multiple select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

So, When I do a:

```
<%= f.input :categories, :required => false, :as => :select, :input_html => {:size => 29, :multiple => true}, :collection => CategoriesList.all %>
```

I currently have:

```
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="select input optional" id="filters_categories_input">
    <input name="filters[categories][]" type="hidden" value="">
    <label class=" control-label" for="filters_categories">Categories</label>
    <input name="filters[categories][]" type="hidden" value="">
    <select id="filters_categories" multiple="multiple" name="filters[categories][]" size="29"><option value="133">Bathroom Remodeling</option>
        <option value="134">Cabinets &amp; Carpenters</option>
        <option value="136">Demolition</option>
        <option value="137">Drywall</option>
        <option value="139">Electricians</option>
        <option value="141">Fences, Doors &amp; Gates</option>
        <option value="143">Flooring</option>
        <option value="144">General Contractors</option>
        <option value="145">Heating &amp; Air Conditioning</option>
        <option value="146">Kitchen Remodeling</option>
        <option value="147">Landscaping</option>
        <option value="149">Painters</option>
        <option value="150">Plumbers</option>
        <option value="151">Roofing</option>
        <option value="152">Swimming Pools</option>
        <option value="154">Windows &amp; Blinds</option>
        <option value="14377">Architects</option>
        <option value="14379">Alarms, Audio &amp; Video</option>
        <option value="14381">Interior Designers</option>
        <option value="14382">Pool Services</option>
        <option value="36608">Cleaning Services</option>
        <option value="37012">Commercial Contractors</option>
        <option value="37013">Custom Home Builders</option>
        <option value="37014">Handymen</option>
        <option value="37045">Locksmiths</option>
        <option value="37074">Home Inspectors</option>
        <option value="37080">Hauling Services</option>
        <option value="37086">Telecommunications</option>
        <option value="40301">Concrete</option>
        <option value="55555">Remodeling</option></select>   
</div>
</div>
```

But I have to integrate a twitter bootstrap template and I would like the select generated  to look like as much as possible like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Multiple Select input</label>
<div class="controls">                                  <select multiple>                                   <option>First option</option>                                       <option selected>Second option</option>                             <option>Third option</option>
<option>Fourth option</option>
<option>Fifth option</option>
<option>Sixth option</option>
<option>Seventh option</option>
<option>Eighth option</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

But I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1)**
First, split your f.input into f.label and f.select,
so that it would look like:

```
<%=f.label "Multiple Select Input"%>
<%= f.select :categories, CategoriesList.all.collect {|x| [x.category, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

Then wrap it with the required div:

```
<div class="control-group">
<%=f.label "Multiple Select Input", :class => "control-label"%>
    <%= f.select :categories, CategoriesList.all.collect {|x| [x.category, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, :class => "controls" %>
</div>
```

**Option 2)** 
Use [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem which would take care of the styling.

Answer (score 0):

f.select doesn't accept more than four arguments. So the statement

```
<%= f.select :categories, CategoriesList.all.collect {|x| [x.category, x.id]}, {},:multiple => true, :class => "controls" %>
```

will throw error. Instead you can do something like below:

```
<%= f.select :categories, CategoriesList.all.collect {|x| [x.category, x.id]}, {},{:multiple => true, :class => "controls"} %>
```